# Ajax отправка атрибутов

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Собираю атрибуты с элемента:

```
var attributes = elem_name.attributes;
text = ''
for (var key in attributes) {
  /* Выбираем именно html-атрибуты */
  if (attributes[key].nodeName) {
    text += attributes[key].nodeName + ':' + attributes[key].nodeValue + ','
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь отправить:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index.php",
  data: text
}).done(function( data ) {
  //
});
```

При просмотре в консоле обнаруживается двоеточие в конце строки с отправляемыми атрибутами: сlass:elem,id:9,:
Проблема не в запятой в конце, ее я пробовал удалять.

На сервере все стандартно:

```
$сlass= $_GET['сlass'];
$id= $_GET['id'];

$con = mysqli_connect('bla','bla','bla','bla');
$result = mysqli_query ($con,"INSERT INTO bla (class, id) VALUES ('$class','$id')");
```

При отправке данных в таблице появляется новая строка, но без значений

Comment: в одинарных кавычках не совсем правильно VALUES ('$class','$id')" и вообще лучше бы конкатекацией значения переменных вставлять.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO bla (class, id) VALUES (" . $class . "," . $id . ")"` но где тут безопасность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно передаете параметры(query):

Стандарт

`var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3`

У вас

`var1:val1,var2:val2,var3:val3,`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111529/how-to-create-query-parameters-in-javascript

```
for (var key in attributes) {
  /* Выбираем именно html-атрибуты */
  if (attributes[key].nodeName) {
    text += attributes[key].nodeName + ':' + attributes[key].nodeValue + ','
  }
}
```

Станет

```
var ret = [];
for (var key in attributes) {
  /* Выбираем именно html-атрибуты */
  if (attributes[key].nodeName) {
    ret.push(encodeURIComponent(attributes[key].nodeName) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(attributes[key].nodeValue));
  }
}

var text = ret.join('&');
```

**ПС**

`jquery.ajax()` для параметра `data` может принять обычный массив/объект и всё за вас отформатировать.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index.php",
  data: {"var1":"val1", "var2": "val2", "var4": "val4"}
}).done(function( data ) {
  //
});
```

**ППС**

У вас в коде SQLInjection

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Правильно ли я понял - sql инъекцию исключит этот код: (class, id) VALUES (" . $class . "," . $id . ")"?

Comment: @Nik Да вы поняли правильно.